# SQL error: 'database.table.field isn't in GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am getting this when I am installing a 3rd party software. I've read the related topics and all of them suggested to set `sql_mode` to an empty string (`SET sql_mode = ''`) but that solution didn't work for me. Still getting the same error. Do I need to set this in my config file or something?

Here's some useful info;

`Server version: 5.6.15-56-log Percona Server (GPL), Release rel63.0, Revision 519`

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| sql_mode      |       |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And the failing query with error message is;

```
mySQL query error: SELECT MAX(e.entry_id) as max, MAX(e.entry_date) as maxdate,b.blog_id, b.blog_name, b.blog_seo_name FROM blog_entries e  LEFT JOIN blog_blogs b ON ( b.blog_id=e.blog_id )   WHERE e.entry_status='published' AND e.entry_banish=0 AND e.entry_featured=0 AND b.blog_view_level='public' AND b.blog_disabled=0 GROUP BY e.blog_id, b.blog_name, b.blog_seo_name ORDER BY maxdate DESC LIMIT 0,50

SQL error: 'db_name_ipb.b.blog_id' isn't in GROUP BY
SQL error code: 1055
```

Any idea ?

### UPDATE

Unfortunately the codes are encrypted, so there is no way to try your suggestions. Also -as specified above- changing the SQL mode didn't solve my problem. I'll continue to investigate and update the question in case a development.

Comment: This is perplexing because this is not the default MySQL behavior.  Perhaps you should try:  `SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;` to see if one of these is set.

Comment: Is the third party software issuing this query? As some answers have pointed out, there's a defect in the query. It looks like you've successfully disabled `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode in the server. But it's barely possible that it's still enabled in your third-party application's session.  You might try disabling it globally with `SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';` and see if your query starts to work.

Comment: Guys, thanks for the comments but I've already tried that. Please see the update.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting `b.blog_id` and grouping by `e.blog_id`. That is the problem.

```
SELECT MAX(e.entry_id) as max, MAX(e.entry_date) as maxdate,b.blog_id, b.blog_name, b.blog_seo_name 
FROM blog_entries e  LEFT JOIN 
     blog_blogs b ON ( b.blog_id=e.blog_id )   
WHERE e.entry_status='published' AND e.entry_banish=0 AND e.entry_featured=0 
     AND b.blog_view_level='public' AND b.blog_disabled=0 
GROUP BY b.blog_id, b.blog_name, b.blog_seo_name 
ORDER BY maxdate DESC LIMIT 0,50
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT MAX(e.entry_id) as max, MAX(e.entry_date) as maxdate, b.blog_id, b.blog_name, b.blog_seo_name
FROM blog_entries e LEFT JOIN
     blog_blogs b
     ON b.blog_id = e.blog_id
WHERE e.entry_status = 'published' AND e.entry_banish = 0 AND
      e.entry_featured = 0 AND b.blog_view_level='public' AND
      b.blog_disabled=0
GROUP BY e.blog_id, b.blog_name, b.blog_seo_name
ORDER BY maxdate DESC
LIMIT 0,50;
```

You have `e.blog_id` in the `group by` but `b.blog_id` in the `select`.  You should choose one or the other.

As a note:  the `left join` can just be an `inner join`. The conditions in the `where` on the `b` table are turning it into an `inner join` anyway.

Note:  MySQL usually does not enforce this.  Your environment must have the [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) mode set, so it is quite suspicious that your SQL mode does not contain anything.  More information on setting SQL modes is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-setting).