# Which laravel query to use to sort top entries according to related table

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have two models: posts and likes. Posts and likes have one-to-many relationship (so, one post has many likes). Likes model has also an `isActive` field which shows liking is active or passive.

I want to get (sort) top 5 posts which had received maximum "active" likes (only likes whose `isActive` field is `true` would be considered).

Which Laravel query could give me the result?

My question is sorting the post not only according to a field of a related model but also count of entries in the related table.

This is the query:

```
$posts = Post::selectRaw('posts.*, count(likings.id) as likes_count')
              ->leftJoin('likings', function ($join) {
                     $join->on('likings.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')
                            ->where('likings.isActive', '=', 1);
              })
              ->groupBy('posts.id')
              ->orderBy('likes_count', 'desc')
              ->take(5)
              ->get();
```

And this is the error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'database.posts.user_id' isn't in GROUP BY 
(SQL: select posts.*, count(likings.id) as likes_count from 'posts' left join 'likings' on 'likings'.'post_id' = 'posts'.'id' and 'likings'.'isActive' = 1 group by 'posts'.'id' order by 'likes_count' desc limit 5)
```

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel order by hasmany relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634921/laravel-order-by-hasmany-relationship)

Comment: I found some different solutions with "count *" but none of them seemed to me exact solution. I can't figure out the way.

Comment: Not a dublicate question. I want to sort the posts based on **count** of active likes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Post::selectRaw('posts.*, count(likes.id) as likes_count')
    ->leftJoin('likes', function ($join) {
        $join->on('likes.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')
             ->where('likes.is_active', '=', 1);
    })
    ->groupBy('posts.id')
    ->orderBy('likes_count', 'desc')
    ->take(5)
    ->get();
```

or subselect:

```
Post::select('*')->selectSub(function ($q) { 
   $q->from('likes')
     ->whereRaw('likes.post_id = posts.id')
     ->where('is_active', 1)
     ->selectRaw('count(*)');
 }, 'likes_count')
 ->orderBy('likes_count', 'desc')
 ->take(5)
 ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you Jarek. I tried it, but gives this error: **posts.user_id isn't in GROUP BY (syntax error or access vioaltion 1055)**. There is no _user_id_ in the query, but in the _posts_ table it exists and gives the owner of the post.

Comment: Yes :) Here it mentions ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode set. Can it be the reason of error? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878604/sql-error-database-table-field-isnt-in-group-by

Comment: And here is that saying "you need to have a full group by". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800411/mysql-isnt-in-group-by

Comment: Paste the code you execute and error you are getting. I won't try to guess.

Comment: @user2356198 It's your mysql config thing: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by You can use subselect instead - see the edit

Answer (score 1):

or just exequte this query

> `Post::with(['likes' => function ($query){
>    $query->where('active', 1);
>   }]);`

and sort it by php if its too hard in mysql. For ex some PostTransformer class

Answer (score 0):

```
    Post::join(DB::raw('(select post_id, count(post_id) as number from likes) as likes_count ON posts.id = likes_count.post_id where likes_count.active = 1'), null)->orderBy('likes_count.number', 'desc')->limit(5);
```

I wrote that without checking this out, so don't hate